# Evaluating Elisp in emacs

Tags: emacs, while-loop, lisp, elisp

I am an hour new into programming in Emacs lisp. I have a little experience with scheme so I understand the big picture of lisps in general. However, I have only used the "pure functional" subset of scheme and do not know how to do practical tasks.

Write now, I know that `C-x C-e` will evaluate the code enclosed by the parentheses' by the current cursor position.

I wish to loop from i = 1 to 10 and print the values of i out. How is this done? I tried the following:

```
(defvar i 1)
(while (< i 11)
  (print "i: " i)
  (setq i (+ i 1)))
```

Emacs tells me: `invalid function 0`.

1. How do I do this correctly?
2. Why is emacs telling me `invalid function 0`

Feel free to give me tips about how to use the scratch buffer (all I know is `C-x C-e` evaluates) in emacs. Thanks for all the help!

**EDIT1:** Could someone tell me how to print out sequential values of `i` using a while loop?

**EDIT2:** When I evaluate the code, it opens up another tiny buffer showing each value of `i` one at a time. However, it is not a large buffer and only shows values of `i` from 13 to 19. When I try to get into that buffer, it closes immediately. How do I "scroll" through that tiny buffer? Note that I use emacs 24.3 through the terminal

**EDIT3:** I figured out that the tiny buffer is the Messages buffer. Is there a better way to view the output of my elisp code? The Messages buffer is full of other junk from evaluating things in emacs.

Comment: `C-h i g (eintr) RET` to begin with, and `C-h i g (elisp)` in general. (and `h` in the info reader to learn how to use that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, enable "Enter debugger on error" from the `Options` menu now and add `(setq debug-on-error t)` or `(custom-set-variables '(debug-on-error t))` to your `~/.emacs.el`.

Then you will get a `*Backtrace*` buffer on <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function 1)
  1(10)
  print("i: " 1)
  (while (< i 11) (print "i: " i) (setq i (+ i 1)))
  eval((while (< i 11) (print "i: " i) (setq i (+ i 1))) nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

which shows that the error comes from `print`.

<kbd>C-h f print RET</kbd> will tell you why, but the upshot is that you want to use `insert` instead of `print` here.

Comment: I used emacs through the terminal. How do I enable "Enter debugger on errror"?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: evaluate the `setq` form in my answer.

Comment: I put the `setq` in my `.emacs` file and tried evaluating the `setq` in my scratch buffer. When I try to evaluate the code it still gives the same errors... However, the debugger appears when I start emacs because of something I am loading. So it is interesting that it works for that case...

Comment: you get the error but the debugger lets you figure out the source of the error.

Answer (score 3):

Just as an added note, since you mentioned knowing some scheme -- if you like the interactive REPL that you can use in typical scheme environment, you might like ielm -- I think it probably stands for Interactive Emacs Lisp mode.  Not sure.  Anyway, `M-x ielm RET` will open up an emacs lisp REPL.  Sometimes it is actually useful -- for example, when you want to inspect the content of a variable with a lot of data in it, ielm will print the whole thing out. Ielm is built in to my Emacs.  Not sure when it was added to the standard distribution, but the earliest copyright in the source says 1994, so it is probably in your Emacs.

Comment: Inferior Emacs Lisp Mode actually.

Comment: Very helpful! But I still can't print out sequential values of `i`

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate Emacs-Lisp sexps in `*scratch*` or in any other buffer in the same mode or (my preference) in mode `emacs-lisp-mode`.

In `*scratch*` you need only hit `C-j` (newline) after a sexp to evaluate it.  In an `emacs-lisp-mode` buffer you can, as you said, use `C-x C-e` after a sexp.  Or you can use `M-x evaluate-region` after selecting one or more sexps.  As always, `C-h m` in any mode tells you about it, and usually lists important key bindings.

You can also check a global variable value using `C-h v SOME-VAR`.  And you can evaluate any sexp on the fly from the minibuffer, using `M-:`.  For example: `M-: (setq foo (+ 42 (length bar)))`

Wrt the debugger:

- As @sds mentioned, `debug-on-error` puts you in the debugger when an error is raised.  You can also set `debug-on-quit` and then enter the debugger using `C-g` to quit (e.g., during a loop).
- If you know the function you want to debug, you can use `M-x debug-on-entry`.
- Step through the debugger using `d`, or skip to the end of a step using `c`.  Use `q` to quit the debugger.
- You can also insert calls to function `debug` in source code, as debugger entry points: `(debug)`.

The backtrace in the debugger is always more informative if you load the relevant source file e.g., `foo.el`, instead of the byte-compiled file, e.g., `foo.elc`.  So before you use `M-x debug-on-entry` use `C-h f` to find out which file the function is defined in, and then load that file using `M-x load-file /path/to/the/file.el`.

There is also another debugger, besides `debug` -- look for `edebug` in the Elisp manual.  Some people prefer `edebug`; I prefer `debug`.